# Adding Calendar Events to Zimbra

Tags: zimbra

I need to add calendar events to Zimbra. Currently I am using Zimbra.Client dll, I am a very new to this, Any idea bosy have an idea how to do that?

Answer (score 1):

Go into GUI, go to Calendar, at the top left, you should see "New Calendar" where you can add your Calendar.